# Combining imperative mode with the implication of the action

Tags: grammar, compound-sentences

I have two sentences:

```
1) Do something.
2) That (the action you performed) will make another thing happen.
```

I'm trying to combine these sentences into one, as they sound dumb to me when used separately. So far I think it should be like this:

```
Do something, which will make another thing happen.
```

but I'm not sure if it's correct.

EDIT: Actually, I'm asking for a general rule, but the specific example is:

```
Press the button. That will make a list with country names appear.
```

Comment: A specific example would be really helpful!

Comment: As in "Risk your life that others may be saved?

Comment: @deadrat I added an example.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters I added an example.

Comment: @id256 "Press the button, and a list with country names will appear."

Comment: How about "Press the button to see a list of country names"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example that you provided, there are a lot of constructions you could use (that will work for many other cases as well):

> > Pressing the button will make a list of countries appear.
> >
> > Press the button in order to see a list of countries.
> >
> > Press the button, and a list of countries will be displayed.
> >
> > Press the button if you want to see a list of countries.

Comment: Press the button to see a list of countries.

Comment: Laugh, and the world laughs with you.

Answer (score -1):

Press the button, so u can see a list of countries

Comment: Hello, Sosoniaf20. Normal spelling is much preferred on ELU.